# What do the std::equal overloads do?

Tags: stl, c++14

I'm looking at the recent c++14 overloads for `std::equal`, and I can't figure out just what they do and are used for...

The two overloads are:

```
template< class InputIt1, class InputIt2 >
bool equal( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, 
            InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2 );

template< class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class BinaryPredicate >
bool equal( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, 
            InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
            BinaryPredicate p );
```

I fully understand the traditional `std::equal` that uses just one `InputIt2`, but the second `InputIt2 last2` is twisting my brain. Could someone explain and give an example of this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The new overloads are actually pretty great. You pass in two full ranges, beginning and end, and rather than run off the end of the shorter one and invoke undefined behaviour, the algorithm stops.

Such improvements were also added to `std::mismatch` and `std::is_permutation`. You can read more about this in [the proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3671.html)

For [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal), the algorithm will simply return `false` if the lengths are not equal.
For [`std::mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch), if the algorithm hits the end of one range, it will return that iterator and the corresponding iterator from the other range.
For [`std::is_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation), the algorithm will also simply return `false` if the ranges are not equal in length.

For reasoning about why, consider that the programmer checking the length is not necessarily possible or cheap. A range obtained from a `std::list` without the original list would need to be traversed through to get the size. A range that uses an `InputIterator`, such as for reading from standard input, is potentially infinite until it hits an end, and it is only allowed to be traversed through once, so the algorithm could no longer use it after you do that. Thank Benjamin Lindley below for that last example.

Comment: It picks the *shorter* one? That actually sounds awful. Shouldn't it return false if they have different lengths??

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast so If i were to pass in two ranges, the first being size `8` and the second being size `3`, it will compare only the first 3?

Comment: @SyntacticFructose, Yes, that's what happens.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal: if they are different lengths then the function will return false.

Comment: It seems something like this should be the responsibility of the programmer to correctly compare ranges rather than create more overloads for `equals` and `mismatch`...huh.. EDIT: @bstamour has a good point

Comment: Sorry about that. Allow me to fix my answer. I think I might have been going from `std::mismatch` more so than the others.

Comment: @SyntacticFructose: Sometimes you don't know the length of a range. For example, with `istream_iterator`.

Comment: @SyntacticFructose, The main point of the proposal is rather to prevent undefined behaviour without forcing the programmer to check. This check can sometimes not be so trivial. For example, when using a pair of `ForwardIterator`s, you'd need to traverse through to check the length. And Benjamin has a great point. If you check the length of that given range, you've invalidated it. Perhaps this information would be better in the answer itself.

Comment: Consider comparing "0123456789" with "012345". If you have three iterators `(begin1, end1, begin2)`, the algorithm may run off the end of the second sequence. If you have (begin1, end1, begin2, end2)`, you can make sure that this doesn't happen.